# Why Inductor reactance 180 ohms?

Tags: oscillator, inductor, impedance

Why is the inductor reactance 180 ohms for designing Voltage controlled Oscillators ( or oscillators maybe ?)

I came across a few resources for designing oscillators, colpitts and hartley specifically. Everywhere they mention that the inductor reactance must be 180 ohms.

[image]

Can anyone explain why ?

http://www.electronics-tutorials.com/oscillators/voltage-controlled-oscillators.htm

( I've been searching the links for hours now. And all I find is a web of links, nothing useful.)

(Aside : Is it standard, or has the author assumed it just like so for his convenience ?)
Thanks.

Comment: It looks like a resistor from the circuit.....

Comment: Nope. Earlier also one guy posted an answer thinking I had mistaken it for that resistor and when I pointed that I had not, he had to delete the answer. So its best you let this comment here.                                                        This is what the article says "the inductor should have a reactance of about 180 ohms. So around the frequency of interest I expect an inductor of about 15 uH to be used for L1 in Fig 2. " The frequency he mentions is 1.8 to 2 MHz. But how did he came on 180 ohm reactance ?

Comment: Reactance and Resistance are 2 different things... L1 could have a reactance of 180 ohms but the resistor attached to the +12V looks to be there to prevent excessive current flowing through FET to the output... like just in case it is shorted to ground.

Comment: But that only works for DC coupled out ..oops my mistake. this is AC coupled....and part of the feed baxk loop

Comment: It doesn't need to be 180 ohms so I think you should link the quote.

Comment: If it's an inductor you should ***draw*** it as an inductor, and give its value in Henries, mH, uH, etc. If it's an inductor with a specific reactance you need to cite the frequency concerned. If you draw it as a resistor, as here, it's a resistor.

Comment: @EJP...did you bother to read earlier comments ? I mentioned that guys are mistaking it for a resistor, but its not so. And I've mentioned frequency as well.

Comment: You say you spent hours searching, but did you try asking the author directly?

Comment: @DaveTweed 's suggestion is worth following- especially since he says he's trying to teach people electronics. An edit to the question when/if you get a response would be appreciated.

Comment: Right. I'll try asking him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I can figure is that he wants the Q of the tuned circuit to be about 15 (his rule of thumb, perhaps), and the 180 follows from that, the 25% tap, and gm of around 6000\$\mu S\$ for the 2N4416A.

That is because Q is the ratio of resistance to inductive reactance in a parallel RLC circuit, and the impedance looking into the JFET source is the reciprocal of the transconductance, of course.

As others have pointed out there is nothing magic about that exact value, and if my surmise is correct, it would change somewhat for different tap positions or JFETs.

Answer (score 2):

Reactance of an inductor equals \$2\pi f L\$, where f is the frequency applied to the inductor.

The OP shows an oscillator that is frequency controlled by a varactor.

Therefore the inductor's reactance cannot be held constant because of frequency changes due to the varactor. It may coincidentally be 180 ohms at one frequency but as the varactor retunes the frequency, the inductor's reactance will increase or decrease.

I've built plenty of RF oscillators recently: -

- 80 MHz used a 430 nH therefore XL = 216 ohms
- 400 MHz used about 15nH (from memory) = 38 ohms

Clearly the impedance doesn't want to be several kohms at RF because of the generally low impedances but also it can't or shouldn't be exactly 180 ohms.

Comment: Ok. In the link I mentioned above, the guy has everywhere mentioned 180 ohms for inductor in oscillators. So I thought it might be some standard or so.

Comment: @Plutoniumsmuggler It's probably not a bad rule of thumb for a certain range of frequencies but as UHF approaches this rule of thumb is not realistically very useful due to track inductance and parasitic capacitance. Also I've designed metal detectors that had an inductance of 1uH and operated as low as 50 kHz - XL is about 0.3 ohms. Horses for courses.